# Найти сумму элементов правой диагонали и произведение элементов левой диагонали

Tags: python

```
 def func(matrix):
    left = 1
    sum = 0
    for i,j in enumerate(matrix):
        left *= matrix[i][i]
        sum += matrix(j[-(i + 1)])
    print(left,sum)
m = [[1, 8, 7],
     [1, 9, 9],
     [2, 3, 8]]
print(func(m))
C произведением все отлично, но с суммой не могу понять в чем проблема. К элемента диагонали может не верно обращаюсь. Благодарю заранее!!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
left *= matrix[i][i]

sum += matrix(j[-(i + 1)])
```

а как именно вы обращаетесь к матрице по 2м индексам? что круглые скобки должны символизировать?

можно так сделать (к примеру):

```
for i, j in enumerate(matrix):
    left *= matrix[i][i]
    sum += matrix[i][len(j) - i - 1]
```

вот так даже попроще будет:

```
for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
    left *= row[i]
    sum += row[-i - 1]
```

Comment: Не до конца еще разобралась с операциями с матрицами. Нашла подсказку по обращению к побочной диагонали матрицы выглядит так [i,n-i+1].  Теперь еще больше путаницы в голове(((

Comment: @Дарья Лазарева, у вас матрица - это список списков или список рядов, через `enumerate` вы можете получить ряд и номер ряда, а дальше совсем просто - работайте не с матрицами, а с рядами (по сути со списками) - посмотрите я дописал в конце своего ответа код

Answer (score 0):

Вот, на всякий случай, решение с numpy:

```
import numpy as np
m = [[1, 8, 7],
     [1, 9, 9],
     [2, 3, 8]]

arr=np.array(m)
my_sum = sum(np.diag(arr)) # 18
my_prod = np.prod(np.diag(np.rot90(arr))) # 126
```